# Drag and Drop catch cell value just dropped in

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, cell, sapui5

I am currently building a sapui5 based app. I want to implement the following scenario: my view contains an instance of sap.ui.table.Table. I enabled the first row for writing. User picks up a string from a MS tool like email and/or word and moves it to the

first cell of the table

```
(id : __field0-col0-row0 )
```

and drops it there.

I am able to catch the drop event and start processing. I am not able to access the new value provided by the drag'n drop. I tried various things:

Referenced the cell by calling

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId('__field0-col0-row0').getValue()
```

I referenced the cell as the webdoc element like this

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId('__field0-col0-row0').$().find('input')
```

I delayed the function, in which I read the value by a second with

```
jQuery.sap.delayedCall(1000, oControlleroAR, "fInitializeModelForTab", [this]);
```

Just after calling the function this way I try to move the focus from the cell, where I dropped the value in to the next one by running

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId('__field1-col1-row0').$().focus()
```

I observed in debugger (Chrome) that the value appears in the control, when focus is moved. 
Nevertheless the value is in almost any case "", empty.

Since I am running out of ideas it would be helpful to get new once, or maybe even a hint how to solve this issue.

This code handles the "drop event":

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("__table0").getRows()[0].getCells()[0].attachBrowserEvent(
                "drop",function(evt) {
                        jQuery.sap.delayedCall(1000, oControlleroAR, "fInitializeModelForTab", [this]);
                        sap.ui.getCore().byId('__field1-col1-row0').setValue("X");
                        sap.ui.getCore().byId('__field1-col1-row0').$().focus();
                });
```

Comment: Please consider a better formatting of your question. It is hard to read.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for making me aware about readability issues. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @Belarophon01 where from string pickup? String isn't an object in html. May your string in div, p, span, etc.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Sure. But you can move the value over via Drag'n Drop to the sapui5 table cell and drop it there. Value appears in the cell then. But I can't access this new value in the drop event callback. That's the problem I want to solve.

Comment: Please add the code how you handle the event.

Comment: @matbtt Code added. Please see above.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this. The drop event I get in the listener as input contains an attribute originalEvent. In this the value can be found. My code now looks like this:

```
var strDragedValue = evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text');
```